# Pick relevant value in a set of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

It might be an easy question for DBA, but not for me.
I have a simplified Family table that looks like that: (part1 and part2 are ids)

| famid | indiv1 | indiv2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **42** | 27 |
| 2 | 33 | 22 |
| 3 | **42** | 12 |
| 4 | 22 | **42** |
| 5 | **42** | 27 |

I can easily retrieve all families that match part1=X or part2=X
But the requested output format is to produce only the famid AND (part1 value or part2 value) BUT without the column that matches the value X.
For example, for a value of 42, the query should return:
[[1,27], [3,12], [4,22], [5,27]]
I would like to know if there is a 'simple' way to produce such a result with SQL query (or sequelize) only, but without a stored procedure.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only have two columns to check and want to return the one that doesn't = X then you want to use a CASE statement to check if Indiv1 = 42.  Then if it is return Indiv2 otherwise return Indiv1.

```
SELECT FamID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Indiv1 = 42
            THEN Indiv2
        ELSE Indiv1
        END AS Indiv
FROM Family
WHERE Indiv1 = 42
    OR Indiv2 = 42
```

[See my SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebd1ec/2)